# Drop foreign key in knex.js migration is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am using migration using knex.js on my sql .
now there is some wrong foreign key and i want to remove it .
I am using below syntax for that but it is not working .
It is not showing any error but not removing foreign key also .

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
      knex.schema.table('page_block_data', function(table) {
        table.dropForeign('page_block_data_block_id_foreign');
      });

};

exports.down = () => {};
```

Can anyone help me for this issue ..?

Answer (score 7):

You are missing return from your up method. It may cause that DB connection is actually closed before query was sent to the DB server.

Also name table name prefix and postfix parts of the foreign key name is automatically generated.

try:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
     return knex.schema.table('page_block_data', function(table) {
        table.dropForeign('block_id');
      });
};
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, so foreign key name was wrong and return was missing. Here is test code showing output SQL https://runkit.com/embed/g9hnti09kaku

Comment: I deleted my answer (since this one was more correct and should be most voted) and added some additional explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

It need a readonly string[]. Maybe you can try:

```
table.dropForeign(['page_block_data_block_id_foreign']);
```

Comment: try `table.dropForeign([], "page_block_data_block_id_foreign");`

Answer (score 0):

It must be alter table and the column is a readonly string, like this:

```
await knex.schema.alterTable('page_block_data', (table) => {
    table.dropForeign(['page_block_data_block_id_foreign']);
});
```